# is there a way to looping mysql data and execute it

Tags: python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

when i try to execute, its only loop first but not execute it to webdriver browser
is there a  way to loop through and execute each data from mysql database to python ?

```py
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import mysql.connector
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

koneksi=mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.100.9',user='streamga',password='ownerpp170896',db='theprimebot',port='3306')
config=koneksi.cursor()

config.execute("select * from data_user")
rows=config.fetchall()

for r in rows :
    phonenum={r[0]}
    passwordStr={r[1]}

#i want to make every looping inserted to here
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(("http://192.168.100.9/pytontest"))
phone = browser.find_element_by_id('popupPhone')
phone.send_keys(phonenum)
pass_login = browser.find_element_by_id('popupPassword')
pass_login.send_keys(passwordStr)
loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_id('popupLoginBtn')
loginbutton.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: what's the Traceback of your error? can you add into your post?

Comment: @KurumiTokisaki no traceback sir, but  its only loop but not execute it to webdriver browser , i want to make when data is looping its also executing until login button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no traceback available, here are a few suggestions you may refer to

1. make sure firefox web driver is installed
2. the inputs shall not be sets (not like {...}) but string
3. the selenium logic shall be part of the loop
4. close the browser at end of each loop if applicable

```
for r in rows :
    phonenum=r[0]
    passwordStr=r[1]
    browser = webdriver.Firefox("/path/to/webdriver")
    browser.get(("http://192.168.100.9/pytontest"))
    phone = browser.find_element_by_id('popupPhone')
    phone.send_keys(phonenum)
    pass_login = browser.find_element_by_id('popupPassword')
    pass_login.send_keys(passwordStr)
    loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_id('popupLoginBtn')
    loginbutton.click()
    browser.quit()
    time.sleep(5)
```